# Alternative URL for shop in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having an eCommerce shop based on wooCommerce Platform for WordPress. If I access the shop page like http://mysiteurl/shop then it shows the available product list.

My requirement is to have an alternative URL of shop for sponsors like http://mysiteurl/shop/sponsor/sponsorname. I need this link to track which order is sponsored by which sponsor, so that I can give appropriate commission to my sponsors.

I don't have too much knowledge of php/wordpress/woocommerce but after doing some R&D I am able to create alternative URL for shop as required by URL rewriting. For URL rewriting I have done following code in functions.php under theme folder.

```
add_action('init', 'custom_shop_sponsor');

function custom_shop_sponsor() {
add_rewrite_tag('%sponsor%','([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^shop/sponsor/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?
pagename=shop&sponsor=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

After doing above code I am able to access the shop page with desired URL like http://mysiteurl/shop/sponsor/sponsorname but on this page no product list is coming. It is just showing text "Showing The Single Result"

[image]

Why are products not coming? Also please suggest any if any other solution exist for my requirement.

Comment: Where would you find "sponsorname" in the product ? Is every sponsor considered as product category in your case ?

Comment: Hi Arfeen. Thanks for your comment. Sponsorname is not related to any product or category. Actually we need a concept of sponsorship in which  a sponsor will send a url http://mysiteurl/shop/sponsor/{sponsorname} to the customer.  When customer will click this url,  the shop page will be opened with product list and customer can buy these products as a normal flow of woocommerce but meanwhile in background we will store the sponsor name in session from reading it from url. And when the customer will complete the order,  we will save the order id along with sponsorname in DB.